# Make a "ditch" function for electric field purpose

Tags: plotting

[image: Test]

I'm trying to make a function to simulate a finite bar and get the electric field, i did it by put 22 funnels together but is too slow and is not very accurate; does anyone have any function to replace this thing?

PD: this function is:

```
Total[Table[1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y + i)^2], {i, -5, 5, 0.5}]]
```

Final Result:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: How about just replacing the summation with an integral? `Integrate[1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y + t)^2], {t, -5, 5}, Assumptions -> {x, y} \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: I love you! it works

Answer (score 2):

By adding up lots of closely spaced contributions, you are effectively [approximating an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method). Just evaluate the integral analytically instead:

```
f[x_, y_] := Evaluate[Integrate[1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y + t)^2], {t, -5, 5},
                                Assumptions -> {x, y} \[Element] Reals]]
```

The assumptions are helpful because otherwise Mathematica assumes $x$ and $y$ to be complex, and spends a much longer time getting to essentially the same result.

(P.S. This probably differs from your expression by roughly a factor of 2. If your expression was really an approximation of the integral, it would have the sum multiplied by the spacing between points, *i.e.* 0.5 in your case.)